# Laravel 5.5 s3 URL

Tags: php, amazon-s3, laravel-5.5

I can upload images to amazon S3 buckets with ease, but I want to get the URL for those images. For example `https://s3.amazonaws.com/MY-BUCKET/IMAGE_NAME`.

I tried using laravel filesystem for example

```
$disk = Storage::disk(‘s3’)->get(‘image_name’);
```

Please correct my question structure so I can learn to ask questions more clearer.

Comment: [`Storage::disk('s3')->url('image_name');`](https://laravel.com/docs/filesystem#file-urls)

Comment: Thank you, it works, I read the documentation before and i saw this topic but I didn’t pay attention to it. Thank you once again.